# Creating struct array with member pointing to either int or short int?

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a data structure which is an array of structs.  The struct has a pointer to either `unsigned int` or `unsigned short int`.

My first attempt is having the struct's data member point to a base class.  The base class has two derived classes.  Both g++ and clang gave an error *(no member named 'myArray' in 'Base')*

In my second attempt, I used void pointer, but both compilers again gave an error *(error: subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'void')*

```
struct Base { uint32_t *x; };
struct Derived16 : public Base { uint16_t *myArray; };
struct Derived32 : public Base { uint32_t *myArray; };

struct SpecialStruct {
    char *name;
    uint32_t id;
    Base *specialArray;
};

struct SpecialStruct2 {
    char *name;
    uint32_t id;
    void *specialArray;
};

int main() {
    // First Attempt
    SpecialStruct myStructs[10];
    myStructs[0].specialArray = new Derived32;
    myStructs[1].specialArray = new Derived16;

    myStructs[0].specialArray->x = new uint32_t[10];
    myStructs[0].specialArray->myArray = new uint32_t[10];
    // ^-- error: no member named 'myArray' in 'Base'

    // Second Attempt
    SpecialStruct2 myStructs2[10];
    myStructs2[0].specialArray = new uint32_t[10];
    myStructs2[1].specialArray = new uint16_t[10];

    myStructs2[1].specialArray[0] = 1;
    // ^-- error: subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'void'

    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to achieve my imaginary data structure?
2. Why can't I access derived class data members?

Comment: If you want to access the data behind a `void` pointer, you *have* to cast that pointer (which means you *have* to know what type of data it is pointing to). As for the "base class" solution, you have the same problem: to access the array from the base class, it has to be declared in it. And child classes cannot re-declare an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
struct BaseStruct{
  virtual ~BaseStruct() {}
};

template<class T>
struct SpecialStruct: public BaseStruct{
  char *name;
  uint32_t id;
  T * spcialArray;
  public:
    virtual ~SpecialStruct(){}
};


int main() {

    // First Attempt
    vector < BaseStruct*> myStructs;

    SpecialStruct<uint32_t> * myStruct =new SpecialStruct<uint32_t>;
    myStruct->spcialArray = new uint32_t[10];
    myStruct->spcialArray[0] = 1;

    myStructs.push_back(myStruct);
    SpecialStruct<uint32_t>* t = (SpecialStruct<uint32_t>*) myStructs[0];
    cout << t->spcialArray[0];
    return 0;
}
```

You can also use unique_ptr for vector and add virtual methods to Struct

Comment: why Do we need to override the destructor ?

Comment: My habit, in this case you don't need it.

Comment: I think you are right as general rule the base destructor "must" be virtual. I found the following comment in Professional C++, third Edition, Chapter 9

Comment: "Notice that the destructors are all virtual. As a rule of thumb, all destructors should be declared virtual. If the preceding destructors were not declared virtual, the code would continue to work fine. However, if code ever called delete on a base class pointer that was really pointing to a derived class, the destruction chain would begin in the wrong place. For example, the following code is similar to the previous example but the destructors are not virtual. This becomes a problem when a Child object is accessed as a pointer to a Parent and deleted."

Answer (score 2):

The "proper" solution would be to use *templates*. But to solve your problem, a `void*` can point to *anything* and the compiler don't know what it actually points to. You have to cast the pointer to the correct type:

```
static_cast<Derived32*>(myStructs[0].spcialArray)->x = ...;
```

Comment: thanks for the correction, and I would be very thankful if you explain how to use templates to solve this problem.